# How to import one repository's .targets file in another repository in gitlab?

Tags: .net, git, msbuild, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a repository `product-config` in gitlab that contains settings/configurations that are shared by the rest of the repositories.

So for e.g. I have a repository `ec-firmware-service` which has `.productConfiguration.targets` file which imports `.target` file of `product-config` repository like this

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\product-config\.msbuild\TransformApplicationConfig.targets" />
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\product-config\.msbuild\TaskConfigPreprocessor.targets" />
```

And `product-config` repository does have these target files but I am still getting this build error

```
C:\builds\engineering\myproject\swc\ec-firmware-service\Configuration\\.productConfiguration.targets(5,3):
error MSB4019: The imported project
"C:\builds\engineering\myproject\swc\product-config\\.msbuild\TransformApplicationConfig.targets"
was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
"C:\builds\engineering\myproject\swc\ec-firmware-service\Configuration\\..\\..\product-config\\.msbuild\TransformApplicationConfig.targets"
is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
[C:\builds\engineering\myproject\swc\ec-firmware-service\src\EC.FirmwareService.WebApi\EC.FirmwareService.WebApi.csproj]
```

So basically it is this error

```
The imported project "C:\builds\engineering\myproject\swc\product-config\.msbuild\TransformApplicationConfig.targets" was not found.
```

Which is correct directory and path to the `TransformApplicationConfig.targets` file but it is somehow not able to pick it up.

The only reason that I can see is because it is in different repository.

Is there any way to target files in different repositories in gitlab or what could be the solution?

**Update**

I am targeting to build .net framework solution using this docker image in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk`

One solution that was suggested is to clone the repository to the current repository while building the solution so I tried to do that but the docker image I am using does not include `git` and so could not follow that solution.

So this is what I have written in my gitlab file

```yaml
# Build
Build:
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk
  before_script:
    #- git 
  script:
    - echo $URL
    - cd src
    #- git clone https://${productconfigdeployerusername}:${productconfigdeployerpassword}@gitlab.cpicloudservices.com/engineering/easitrax-connect/swc/product-config.git
    - msbuild /t:restore
    - msbuild EC.FirmwareService.sln /p:Configuration=Release
  only:
    - branches
  tags:
    - windows-runner
  environment:
    name: development
```

You can see the `git clone` line is commented. If I uncomment it, it starts giving error that `git` is not recognized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a new image and install git there, but I have no idea how one would do that in windows.

Instead, you could add a separate job that clones the repository, and exports it as a job artifact. This artifact can then be used by the windows job, removing the need for git in the image.

```yaml
stages:
  - pre-build
  - build

# Build
Clone:
  stage: pre-build
  image: alpine/git
  script:
    - mkdir git
    - cd git
    - git clone https://${productconfigdeployerusername}:${productconfigdeployerpassword}@gitlab.cpicloudservices.com/engineering/easitrax-connect/swc/product-config.git
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - src
    expire_in: 1 day
  needs: []
  only:
    - branches

Build:
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk 
  script:
    - echo $URL
    - cd src
    - msbuild /t:restore
    - msbuild EC.FirmwareService.sln /p:Configuration=Release
  only:
    - branches
  tags:
    - windows-runner
  environment:
    name: development
  needs: ["Clone"]
```

Disclaimer: I did not run this code, it could contain errors.

Comment: Yes. When you use `needs` it just waits for the needs job to be completed but it does not automatically start using the artifacts of the completed job. The part of making it available while job build was the all question. I know you mentioned about using artifacts of the previous job but I don't see any code to do that. Sorry, but the answer is more like an advice of what all can be tried rather than actual helpful code.

Comment: Tried it with `artifacts: true` and it worked!! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know I just tried it even without `needs` tag and it worked even without that :) Because the cloning was happening in `pre-build` so it was available to the `build` stage even without having to add `needs`

Comment: @PawanNogariya I thought the default behavior was to download all artifacts, that's why I didn't include `artifacts: true`. It's indeed true that the `needs` tag is not strictly necessary, since it's in an earlier stage. Using it everywhere does speed up your pipeline though, so I included it out of habit.